# PySide QTabWidget resize event

Tags: python, tabs, resize, pyside, qtabwidget

LS
I have a widget on a tabsheet. During setup of the app window the size of the tabsheet is used to determine the size for the widget. The widget size is then set to fully cover fill the tabsheet. When I resize the window the tab is also resized, but the widget remains at the original size (as from the initialisation). I would like a recalculation for the size of my widget so it can be set to a new size after the tab size has been changed.
I need a trigger that captures a window resize event and then do the widget size recalculation. How can this be done ?
Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this manually, use [widget layouts](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html)

Comment: tnx, but I have multiple widgets on one tabsheet for which I have a layout algorithm based on the size of the tabsheet. I only need the new size and my own layout algoritm will position and size my widgets.